# AWS Amplify push notifications with Expo

Tags: notifications, expo, push, aws-amplify

I'm having an issue when adding push APNs notifications as a service of amplify. I'm follow the next guide https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/push-notifications/getting-started/q/platform/react-native/ and I'm getting the next issue 'Notifications [Error: Unable to find @aws-amplify/rtn-push-notification. ]'

"@aws-amplify/rtn-push-notification": "^1.1.7",
"aws-amplify": "^5.3.11",
"expo": "^49.0.11",

I have removed node modules package-lock.json, and reinstall them. Try another module versions, o start project clearing the cache.

Answer (score 0):

[Amplify Push Notifications is currently only supported for applications created via the React Native CLI](https://docs.amplify.aws/react-native/build-a-backend/push-notifications/set-up-push-notifications/)

[image: Amplify Docs]